# .Net core API can't read resource File in docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a .net 6 web app where I would like to read a resource file.  Nothing complicated, just:

```
  const string consentFileLoc = @"Resources\ConsentBanner.html";

  string consentData = string.Empty;

  if (System.IO.File.Exists(consentFileLoc))
  {
      consentData = await System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync(consentFileLoc);
  }
```

and this works fine when i deploy to an app service, but when i try to deploy to a dockerized container service it can't find the files.  I've investigated the image, and i can see the files, i'm not sure if there are some other permissions i need to be working on for it to work correctly?  My dockerfile is just:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8081

COPY bin/Release/net6/ App/
RUN chmod -R 755 /App/Resources
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "COBRA5API.dll"]
```

Comment: Might just be \ in the filename that should be / since you're on Linux

Comment: Ha!  that was it.  Thank you!